# AADSTS90014: The required field 'request' is missing from the credential

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-b2c

I have given ClientID and TanentID (from my organization, i cannot share it) to use in NodeJS application that will ask me to sign in with email and password, when i run the application microsoft Login window appears and i enter my own email and password. but in return Microsoft is saying the following `AADSTS90014: The required field 'request' is missing from the credential. Ensure that you have all the necessary parameters for the login request.`

Where in need to add the field 'request'. DO i have to contact my admin to grant me admin access or is there something in need to fix in my code.

Comment: i cannot share the code as it is having confidential secrets and in error logs i'm not getting anything.

Comment: ask your admin what is authentication platform they have added, WEB or SPA ?

Comment: am using Node application to create sing function work. but in email my manager has sent me credentials to use in SPA... what is SPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single page application (e.g Angular). if the authentication platform they have added as SPA then you need to create SPA (Single Page Application) with angular.

for demo purpose:
create dummy azure account.

register an application.

select that registered application

under Manage>Authentication>Add Platform

you will see 5 options as following:

WEB, Signle Page Application, iOS/MacOS, Android, Mobile and desktop application.

Your admin has added SPA as Authentication platform.

You can get the tutorial from Official link of MicroSoft [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code)